# How to connect Oracle VirtualBox's RMI client with W8 host's RMI server?

Tags: java, rmi, virtualbox, connection-timeout, windows-firewall

I have a W8 machine with Oracle VirtualBox. In this, I have an ubuntu machine connected with only-host network.

> VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
>
> Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
>
> Allow All

On the host machine I have a java program that acts like an RMI server.

On the virtual machine I have the the java program acting like an RMI client.

The client succeed in getting the registry without any problem, then it hangs when it looks up for the stub. Thus I have:

```
SEVERE: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.bla.bla.bla; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at ...
```

Both RMIclient and RMIserver have all the permissions, and this is the code for the RMI connection:

SERVER SIDE:

```
private static void startServer() {
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.bla.bla.bla");

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", POLICY_FILE_LOC); //all permissions
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try {
        String name = "RemoteController";
        RemoteControllerInterface remote = new RemoteController();
        RemoteControllerInterface stub =
            (RemoteControllerInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remote, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        registry.rebind(name, stub);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }       
}
```

CLIENT SIDE:

```
    RemoteControllerInterface remote = null;

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", POLICY_FILE_LOC); //all permissions
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    try {
        String name = "RemoteController";
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.bla.bla.bla");
        remote  = (RemoteControllerInterface) registry.lookup(name); // stuck here
        remote.connect(); // sample remote method
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I used the same client code running it on the host machine and all works fine, that's why I think is some problem in the configuration of VirtualBox maybe.

Comment: Is the 1099 port open on your host machine?

Comment: yes. Actually I just found that if I completely disable the W8 firewall it works! Now I'd like to know how to configure it to keep it working....

Comment: Personally, I don't use w8, so I can't help with that. I suggest to use the google!

Comment: Google can't help in this... some rare case!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Windows Firewall so these are general guidelines:

You need to not only have port 1099 open on Windows for the RMI registry, you need to have another port open for your server RMI object itself - I think it opens a random port, unfortunately (see other StackOverflow questions on this). Also you may need to allow the VirtualBox host-only network to talk to localhost, as well (yes, I know that's the *whole point* of a host-only network, I'm just saying).

But you don't need to allow any other machines to access your Java programs (right?), so you could just allow unrestricted access from the VirtualBox host-only network, if Windows Firewall lets you configure it to do that.

Comment: ok, I just have to choose the port for every object in the code and that's all. Hope there was a finer solution. Thank you :)